# how to pass variables to the view and fix query laravel

Tags: laravel

I got a form and a database mysql, and i'm trying to do a query that shows me a report of those form submits. In this problem i'm facing , what's happening is that as soon as i add another carplate, and submit some forms, it doesn't make well the calculations being that, i wanted it to be grouped by carPlate and totalKMs, showing a resume of each carplate giving only the sums for each car plate, what i'm noticing is that some of the sums are correct but not well grouped or queried..

//blade

```
 <tr>
                            @foreach ($queryFinal as $item)
                            <td>{{ $item->carplate }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->totalKMs }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->average100 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->totalEurosCharged }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->totalrep }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->totalPorts }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->costKM }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
```

//controller

```
 public function index(Request $request, Repair $valor, Form $kilometrage, Ports $cost)
    {      
        $totalLitersCharged = $kilometrage->sum('liters_charged');
        $totalEurosCharged = $kilometrage->sum('euros_charged');
        $totalrep = $valor->sum('repair.valor');
        $endKmSum = $kilometrage->sum('endkm');
        $totalrep = $valor->sum('repair.valor');
        $currentKilometrage = $kilometrage->sum('kilometrage');
        $cost = $cost->sum('cost');
        $portsEuro = $kilometrage->sum('portsEuro');
        $queryFinal = DB::table("form")
            ->selectRaw("form.carPlate,(form.endKm-form.kilometrage) AS totalKm,(100*SUM(liters_charged))/SUM(form.endKm-form.kilometrage) AS average100,$totalEurosCharged as totalEurosCharged , $totalrep as totalrep  , $cost + $portsEuro as totalPorts, $totalEurosCharged + $totalrep + $portsEuro + $cost / (form.endKm-form.kilometrage) AS costKM")
            ->leftJoin('repair', 'repair.carPlate', '=', 'repair.carPlate')
            ->leftJoin('ports', 'ports.carPlate', '=', 'ports.carPlate')
            ->orderBy("form.carPlate")
            ->groupBy("carPlate","form.endKm","kilometrage")
            ->get();
        return view('admin.form.report', compact('queryFinal','totalrep','cost','portsEuro','totalEurosCharged'));
}
```

Comment: did you try removing the </tr> out of the foreach?

Comment: because you have the initial tr outside the foreach, however the closing tr, is inside the loop, so it will not work

Comment: the first one? <tr>
                            @foreach ($queryFinal as $item)?

Comment: no, this one  </tr> @endforeach

Comment: needs to be  @endforeach </tr>

Comment: yes, it puts the results all in the same row, and its summing some results as one, when i try to group it only by carplate and  totalKMs , it shows an error saying form.endkm and form.kilometrage isnt in groupby .

Comment: in config->database.php, try finding mysql array, and make sure that the strict value is false: 'strict' => false

Comment: i've already tried that and it doesnt work. it keeps summing as one some of the results

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
    @foreach ($queryFinal as $item)
        <td>{{ $item->carplate }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->totalKMs }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->average100 }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->totalEurosCharged }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->totalrep }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->totalPorts }}</td>
        <td>{{ $item->costKM }}</td>
    @endforeach
</tr>  <---- here
```

try it like this

Comment: i understand now that strict false works. ive already tried in the past but not solved, now i need to know why it's not grouping well the results, thanks

Comment: My last sugestions would be, try checking that endkm  and kilometrage exists in the DB, try to make the actual query on phpmyadmin or whatever your using as DB(to see if it's working), add "form" to kilometrage  on groupby()-> groupby(form.kilometrage ), try removing endkm  and kilometrage and check it's working, then add one by one and test where it could be the problem. Last you could try adding all the selected fields to the group by, maybe,because  endkm  and kilometrage may have other values so it needs all the fields, like groupby("carPlate","form.endKm","form.kilometrage"totalKm...)